# Python: is it possible to wrap "@patch(path)" for re-use? (unittest)

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

As the doc ["Where to patch"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) says, we need to patch where an object is looked up, (not where it's defined); so I understand that it's not possible to - let's say - create a reusable patch for a particular path

Imagine you have several modules importing an object you'd like to mock

```py
# file_a.py
from foo.goo.hoo import settings
```

```py
# file_b.py
from foo.goo.hoo import settings
```

```py
# file_c.py
from foo.goo.hoo import settings
```

I was wondering if there is a way to create a decorator such as:

```py
@mock_settings
def test_whatever(self, settings_mock):
    ...
```

instead of this solution:

```py
@patch("some_module.file_a.settings")
def test_whatever(self, settings_mock):
    ...
```

```py
@patch("some_module.file_b.settings")
def test_whatever(self, settings_mock):
    ...
```

```py
@patch("some_module.file_c.settings")
def test_whatever(self, settings_mock):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, to patch an object you have to patch its reference in the module to be tested (in case it is imported using `from ...import`).
To have it patched in several modules, you can patch all of these modules with the same mock, and use that mock. If you know in advance which modules you want to patch, you can just do this. If you *don't* know them in advance, you have to try to patch the object in all loaded modules -- this may get a bit more complicated.

I will show an example using pytest and a pytest fixture, as this is more compact; you could wrap that in a decorator for usage in `unittest`, but that will not change the basics. Consider we have a class that needs to be mocked in several modules:

*class_to_mock.py*

```py
class ClassToMock:
    def foo(self, msg):
        return msg
```

*module1.py*

```py
from class_to_mock import ClassToMock

def do_something():
    inst = ClassToMock()
    return inst.foo("module1")
```

*module2.py*

```py
from class_to_mock import ClassToMock

def do_something_else():
    inst = ClassToMock()
    return inst.foo("module2")
```

You can now write a fixture that mocks the class in all of these modules at once (here using `pytest-mock` for simplicity):

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_class(mocker):
    mocked = Mock()
    for module in ('module1', 'module2'):
        mocker.patch(module + '.ClassToMock', mocked)
    yield mocked
```

This can be used to test both modules:

```py
def test_module1(mocked_class):
    mocked_class.return_value.foo.return_value = 'mocked!'
    assert module1.do_something() == 'mocked!'

def test_module2(mocked_class):
    mocked_class.return_value.foo.return_value = 'mocked!'
    assert module2.do_something_else() == 'mocked!'
```

If you want a generic version that mocks the class in *all* loaded modules, you can replace the fixture with something like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_class(mocker):
    mocked = Mock()
    for name, module in list(sys.modules.items()):
        if not inspect.ismodule(module):
            continue
        for cls_name, cls in module.__dict__.items():
            try:  # need that as inspect may raise for some modules
                if inspect.isclass(cls) and cls_name == "ClassToMock":
                    mocker.patch(name + ".ClassToMock", mocked)
            except Exception:
                continue
    yield mocked
```

This will work for this specific example - to generalize this, it has to consider more object types, the class shall be configurable, and there may be some more issues - opposed to the more simple version where you just enumerate the modules you want to patch, which will always work.

You could do something similar in `unittest.setUp` by putting the mock in an instance variable, though that is less elegant, because you are also responsible for stopping the mocking:

```py
class ModulesTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mocked_class = Mock()
        self.mocks = []
        for module in ('module1', 'module2'):
            mocked = mock.patch(module + '.ClassToMock', self.mocked_class)
            self.mocks.append(mocked)
            mocked.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        for mocked in self.mocks:
            mocked.stop()

    def test_module1(self):
        self.mocked_class.return_value.foo.return_value = 'mocked!'
        assert module1.do_something() == 'mocked!'
```

And you can also wrap this in a decorator, to answer your original question at least partially:

```py
def mocked_class_to_mock(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def _mocked_class_to_mock(*args, **kwargs):
        mocked_class = Mock()
        mocks = []
        for module in ('module1', 'module2'):
            mocked = mock.patch(module + '.ClassToMock', mocked_class)
            mocks.append(mocked)
            mocked.start()
        kwargs['mocked_class'] = mocked_class  # use a keyword arg for simplicity
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        for mocked in mocks:
            mocked.stop()

    return _mocked_class_to_mock

...
    @mocked_class_to_mock
    def test_module3(self, mocked_class):
        mocked_class.return_value.foo.return_value = 'mocked!'
        assert module3.do_something() == 'mocked!'
```

Of course, you can do the same with the more generic version, if needed.

Also note that I skipped the simpler case where the object is imported using `import ...`. In this case, you have to patch the original module. In the generic fixture, you probably want to add that case always.